# Create new column based on current row with calculations involving other rows

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have dataframe like this:

```text
id,month,price
1,2021-04-31,9
1,2021-01-31,5
1,2021-02-31,6
1,2021-03-31,8
```

So for each same `ID` I want to fetch sum of `price` for current row `month-1` and `-2`

For example for row `1,march,8`, I will get output as `5+6=11` in a new column since for current march row past two months are `jan` and `feb`

There will be other `ids` as well in the main data

Comment: what about line `1,jan,5` ? It should get a `null` value or a 0 value ? Do you have the years also ?

Comment: I just pasted a sample data here, want to understand the logic so 0 would be fine you can consider with year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `month` names into month numbers then use it for ordering in a Window partitioned by `id` for running sum:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, "apr", 9), (1, "jan", 5),
    (1, "feb", 6), (1, "march", 8)
], ["id", "month", "price"])

# handle both full and short textual representation of month names
month_number = F.when(F.length("month") == 3, F.month(F.to_date(F.col("month"), "MMM"))) \
    .otherwise(F.month(F.to_date(F.col("month"), "MMMM")))

w = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy(month_number).rangeBetween(-2, -1)

df.withColumn("price_sum", F.sum("price").over(w)).show()

#+---+-----+-----+---------+
#| id|month|price|price_sum|
#+---+-----+-----+---------+
#|  1|  jan|    5|     null|
#|  1|  feb|    6|        5|
#|  1|march|    8|       11|
#|  1|  apr|    9|       14|
#+---+-----+-----+---------+
```

---

For your updated question, you can truncate the dates into month unit then use window with range between `interval -2 months` and `interval -1 months`:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, "2021-04-30", 9), (1, "2021-01-31", 5),
    (1, "2021-02-28", 6), (1, "2021-03-31", 8)
], ["id", "month", "price"])

df.withColumn(
    "date",
    F.date_trunc("month", F.col("month"))
).withColumn(
    "price_sum",
    F.expr("""sum(price) over(partition by id order by date 
                              range between interval 2 months preceding 
                              and interval 1 months preceding)
    """)
).drop("date").show()
```

Comment: Ive edited the question to include a complete date. Date part doesnt matter but for months will be of different years right so a specific mar2021 (ex) cant be used. A date range is useful which can be used like date -2 months

Comment: @EXODIA I added above solution according to your updated question. Please avoid changing your question after it was answered for next times.

Answer (score 0):

Use window function to SUM on price, PARTITION BY month (numeric), and use ROWS to get two preceding rows.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.option("header",True).csv("path/to/file") # Assuming file is csv
df.createOrReplaceTempView('df')
df1 = spark.sql("""
           SELECT id,month,price,
             CASE
               WHEN month = 'jan' THEN 1
               WHEN month = 'feb' THEN 2
               .
               .
               .
               else 12
             END AS month_num
           FROM df 
           """)

df1.createOrReplaceTempView('df1')
spark.sql("""
           SELECT id, month, price,
           SUM(price) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY month_num ROWS 2 PRECEDING) AS price_sum
           FROM df1 
           """).show()
```

Add to the second query

```
WHERE month_num NOT IN (1,2)
```

if you want price_sum 0 for jan & feb.